# Symfony form submit doesn't handle integer type too large

Tags: php, forms, integer, symfony

When I submit a form field as IntegerType or NumberType, the data is not handled if nulber is too large as you can see below :

**Request dumped:**

```
"payment" => array:6 [▼
    "cardType" => "2"
    "cardNumber" => "12345678901"
    "cardCrypto" => "888"
    "cardDate" => array:3 [▶]
    "save" => ""
    "_token" => "6F_YI_XJ9QqG504C9ef5fBL_8wwx6ODCtPKstJnm0KQ"
```

**After handleRequest method, form->getData() dumped:**

```
array:3 [▼
   "cardType" => 2
   "cardDate" => DateTime {#1640 ▶}
   "cardCrypto" => 888
]
```

**The field cardNumber has disappeared.**

Is is related to PHP integer max size ? I am testing it on Windows 64-bits and Symfony 3.
There are no constraints on the field (like Length)

When the value submitted is 1234567890, it works, but with 12345678901 it doesn't.

My solution is to change it to `TextType`-field.

Comment: I would use plain TextType for card number. I don't really see any benefit of considering it as an integer.

Comment: Off topic: I hope you're not storing that card data in database?

Comment: Not only does it not have any benefits, it is just plain **wrong** to treat such data as integers - same as with telefone numbers or postal codes.

Comment: Ok, I will use TextType, but I just wanted to understand this behaviour.

Comment: The benefit is to have a tag input with attribute type="number".
It is possible to specify it on TextType field in twig like this:
{{ form_widget(formPayment.cardNumber, { 'type':'number' }) }}

Answer (score 0):

try changing the column's type to bigint`@ORM\Column(type="bigint")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But it's a credit card payment form, I didn't mapped it to an Entity